# Where do I find my Amazon EC2 Access Logs?

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2

I recently set up an Amazon EC2 Linux instance. I'm wondering, are there logs automatically kept? Or so I have to set them up? If the former, where are they? If the latter, any simple basic logging setup that is recommended?

Comment: What logs are you talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Linux most log files can be found under `/var/log`.

Comment: I found mine in var/log/httpd/access_log but you need to use "sudo su" to access the httpd folder.